# Soldering iron for hakko t12 tips on 12v

Tags: soldering, soldering-iron-station

I considered getting those clone hakko t12 tip compatible soldering iron.

**this is the tutorial I'm following:**

> https://www.instructables.com/id/DIY-Hakko-T12-Compatible-Soldering-Station/

so based from the title, I know you know what I am doing so i'll just get to the point already.

*I'm building those soldering iron kit but I don't have the 24v power supply. I  have however a 12v power supply.*

In theory, the soldering iron will still heat up but slower. I'm fine with slow so will it function or will the circuitry on the controller explode or something. Even if it is slow, As long as it is functioning, I'm fine with it.

**This is what my soldering iron looks like:**

> https://www.ebay.com/itm/Digital-Soldering-Iron-Station-Temperature-Controller-Kits-For-HAKKO-T12-Handle/112555080925?hash=item1a34ce3cdd:m:mhF39lZBeOxALWWO8tNREIQ

Comment: My advice: get a 24V power supply. It's possible the control electronics will work on 12V (probable, even, given that at _this_ price point they probably use a linear regulator), but you won't be able to solder high-thermal-mass components or solder things to ground planes very well.

Comment: we have a general idea of what you are thinking of doing, but we do not know what you are actually doing

Answer (score 2):

Without following the links, your basic problem will be lack of power. The maximum power out of the iron is given by \$ P = \frac {V^2}{R} \$. If you halve the voltage you will only have a maximum of 1/4 of the iron's rated power.

The iron will heat up to the point that the rate of heat loss from the iron is equal to the power input. At 1/4 power I suspect that this may be below the melting point of your solder.

Answer (score -1):

75W @ 24V gets you up to 450’C

20W @ 12V might get you up to 150’C if you wait long enough and don’t use it, at a rate of 60’C/W for thermal loss.

That won’t melt solder very well, right?

What does Ohm’s Law tell you when the resistance of the heater rises with filament temperature?